# Pattern match list with exactly 2 elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I just started learning Haskell and I'm trying to use pattern matching to match a list that has exactly 2 elements. As an exercise, I'm trying to write a function which returns the one but last element from a list. So far I found this:

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast [] = error "Cannot take one but last from empty list!"
myButLast [x] = error "Cannot take one but last from list with only one element!"
myButLast [x:y] = x
myButLast (x:xs) = myButLast xs
```

Now the line with myButLast [x:y] is clearly incorrect, but I don't know how to match a list that has exactly 2 elements, as that is what I'm trying to do there. I read this (http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching) page and it helped me a lot, but I'm not completely there yet...

Comment: You may either write `[x,y]` or `x:y:[]`. They are both equivalent. The pattern `[x:y]` means "match a list that contains exactly one element, which is itself a list, which contains exactly two elements named `x` and `y`", which isn't what you meant.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Oh, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, no, that's wrong... `[x:y]` means `x` is the first element and `y` is the remaining sublist. (Think `[x:xs]`.) Sorry about that... Either way, it's not what you meant.

Comment: Also, your last rule seems in contradiction with the requirement "exactly 2 elements". I would suggest to match what you need first (`[x,_]`), then match anything else with a catch-all pattern (`_`) as an error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast [] = error "empty list"
myButLast [x] = error "too few elements"
myButLast [x, _] = x
myButLast (x: xs) = myButLast xs
```

This is the second quesion in [99 questions](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10).